# Multiple Inserts Oracle Mybatis Spring using Insert All

Tags: oracle, mybatis

I am trying to use Mybatis foreach feature to insert a list of objects to a single table in the Oracle database.

For example purpose, I have a table 'Test_A' which has a single nullable VARCHAR column 'Description'.

I pass a list of Strings to the mybatis method, the mapper of which is mentioned as below.

```
<insert id = "testMultipleInserts"  parameterType="java.util.List">
    Insert All 
    <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index">
        Into Test_A (Description) values (#{element.description})
    </foreach>
    select * from dual
</insert>
```

When I invoke the above method, it prints the following query to the log

```
      Insert All Into Test_A (Description) values (?) Into Test_A (Description) values (?) Into Test_A (Description) values (?) select * from dual
```

which I hope is in the correct syntax as per Oracle dialect (I executed from SQL Browser and this works)

But there seems to be some issue with reading the list elements from the List parameter provided to the method. I am getting an exception as given below.

```
      org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter '__frch_element_0' not found. Available parameters are [list]
```

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have any element.description that is not null? And, why do you "select * from dual"?

Comment: I am passing all non null values in the list to the element.description. Regarding select * from dual, I really am not sure why we have to provide this, But read somewhere that this has to follow the Insert all statement in Oracle. It can be select * from dual or any select query from dual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no Idea about the query you are trying but the stack trace clearly states that its parameter issue change the parameterType from `java.util.List` to `list`

```
<insert id = "testMultipleInserts"  parameterType="list">
    Insert All 
    <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index">
        Into Test_A (Description) values (#{element.description})
    </foreach>
    select * from dual
</insert>
```